# spring not handling unmapped endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm having a problem with a service i'm currently developing. 
I'm using spring-boot 2.

What i'm trying to do is to use an interceptor in order to add a security level at my service. The security service checks if a client can make a request to the service i'm currently developing.
I just basically followed the currently solution that I found in other services which is:

```
@Component
public class AuthorizationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

   @Autowired
   private final SecurityApi securtityApi;

   @Override
   public boolean preHandle(final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                                 final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                                 final Object handler) throws Exception {

   final String path = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();
   final String httpMethod = httpServletRequest.getMethod();
   final Map<String, List<String>> headers = Headers.getAllHeaders(httpServletRequest);

   final Optional<SecurityApiValidationResponse> validationResponse = Optional.ofNullable(securityApi.validateRequest(path, httpMethod, headers));

   validationResponse.filter(SecurityApiValidationResponse::isAllowed)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new UnauthorizedException(ErrorCodes.UNAUTHORIZED));

   return true;
}
```

My problem is, when i make a request to an endpoint not mapped, this UnauthorizedException is thrown and not treated by my advice and later spring redirects to "/error"
In older versions of spring-boot, like 1.4, spring somehow treated this case returning a response of Not Found, avoiding a request to an unmapped endpoint to get to the interceptor level. (It would only get there when redirected to "/error")
This doesn't happen in spring-boot 2 and the interceptor receives the request to the unmapped enpoint, which causes this exception to be thrown.
Any ideas how to avoid this?